# R ggplot2 facet_grid "hierarchical" formatting with 3 variables or more

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm trying to get a nice display when having multiple variables on one dimension of my `facet_grid` so that instead of repeating the name of all variables for each column (or row) I have a merged box over sub-boxes.
Taking a concrete example with a default dataset from R (based on the R Cookbook):

```
library(reshape2)
sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      facet_grid(smoker ~ sex+day)
sp
```

This returns something like the top part of [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huOMs.jpg), with Female/Male being repeated at the top of each column. Is there a way (in R) of instead merging all the gender blocks to get something like the bottom part of the figure I uploaded? (I did this one with Gimp, needless to say it's not an ideal option)

[image]

I looked up the documentation for `facet_grid` and it feels like the solution would be to [create a new labeller function](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labellers.html#writing-new-labeller-functions), but I'm just too new to R to be able to go for it. I've searched a bit more to see if someone had already solved this problem but didn't seem to find any answers.

Does anyone know of a custom labeller function that's been already created for that purpose, or does anyone know how to create such a custom labeller function? That would be just amazing.

Comment: Thanks for finding a duplicate of that question with a working, if not elegant, solution!